# MS Access - Data selection has changed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a small, but elusive problem:

In MS Access, I have a single result form. On this form I have a list. This list is a subselect based on the ID of the main form. How can I capture the row change, and so update my list?

I am NOT looking for Insert / Update Statements! I have them galore, and they work fine, but do not help me unless each row is updated before / as soon as changing rows.

In my example, the list is Genres for a selected Film.

```
Private Sub film_name_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strNewRecord As String
    Dim film_id As Integer

    If IsNull(Forms!Films!film_id) Then
            GoTo cmdNoRecord_Error
    Else:
        film_id = Forms!Films!film_id
        strNewRecord = "SELECT qry_film_genres.gen_name FROM qry_film_genres " _
            & " WHERE film_id = " _
            & film_id & " ORDER BY qry_film_genres.gen_name"
            Me.Genre_List.RowSource = strNewRecord
    End If

    Exit Sub

cmdNoRecord_Error:
   MsgBox "Please Select a Film."
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: The SQL works fine. It's the capture point that's the problem. But thanks. And I didn't put that colon there. Intellisense did and it won't let me remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the film_id Change event. I'm assuming the 'film_id' field is on the parent form, and a subform is where the 'Genre_List' control lives.

EG:

```
Private Sub film_id_Change()
    If Not IsNull(Me.film_id) Then
        Me.CHILDFORM.Genre_List.RowSource = "SELECT qry_film_genres.gen_name FROM qry_film_genres " _
            & " WHERE film_id = " & Me.film_id & " ORDER BY qry_film_genres.gen_name"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using change, but it only seems to trigger on manual changes to a field, not selection changes, or did I miss something? I'll try that again tonight. Thanks

Comment: How else is the field being changed? If it is being changed with VBA, you can simply call the rowsource change after the code that changes film_id.

Another option is to change the rowsource on enter.
EG:
`Private Sub Genre_List_Enter()
    If Not IsNull(Me.Parent.Form.film_id) Then
        Me.Genre_List.RowSource = "SELECT qry_film_genres.gen_name FROM qry_film_genres " _
            & " WHERE film_id = " & Me.Parent.Form.film_id & " ORDER BY qry_film_genres.gen_name"
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: When I was testing (it was late, I was tired / frustrated), if I used the 'Next record' button at the bottom of the form (the one given by MS), the change event wasn't called..? I want to make my own buttons for this later, and will then make sure my function is called, but in the mean time.... and I'm not sure if I can disable those MS buttons?? PS. Sorry I'm a C++ / SQL guy.

Comment: You can hide them (it's a property of the form, look in design view). From what you've described I think you should set the combobox rowsource in design view to 
`SELECT qry_film_genres.gen_name FROM qry_film_genres`
No WHERE clause, then add the code in my last comment to the Enter event of the ComboBox. Finally, use the Current event of the form to reset the rowsource back to:
`SELECT qry_film_genres.gen_name FROM qry_film_genres`
when the current record is moved.
...

Comment: ...[cont]
1. User enters form, rowsource has all possiblities so the stored value will display correctly.
2. User enters ComboBox, VBA updates the rowsource to limit the available options
3. User moves to next record, VBA on Current event resets the rowsource for correct display.

Comment: Thats a great idea, and I think I can use it else where, but this element is a list, and is always shown. Still novel idea, thanks!

Comment: Also, what is this On Current event?? that sounds like what I am looking for, in C++ I have called the event trigger 'OnPutRecord', but vba doesn't have such a function. I think that disabling those MS buttons should work though. Just would be nice to know what the row select event is called.

Comment: object_current()! Thats what I was looking for!! Thank you, thank you, thaaaaank you!!